# sequence limits - proof by definition

Tags: limits, proof-writing, definition

I would like to ask how should I show from the definition of sequence limits that if $\lim a_n = 0$ then $\lim \sqrt{a_n} = 0$. I know how to show it for a specific example, but I don't know how to show it "resulting".

Comment: That is false unless you're talking of complex sequences or else that  $\;\forall\,n\;,\;\;a_n\ge0\;$ .

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your questions. Based on a couple of your previous questions, it looks like you were at least learning it. Some specific tips `$a_n$` produces $a_n$, `$\lim_{n \to \infty}$` produces $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, and `$\sqrt{32}$` produces $\sqrt{32}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition gives
$$\forall\varepsilon>0,~\exists N \in \mathbb N,~ \forall n > N: \quad a_n < \varepsilon^2$$
Then, for these $n$'s we have $\sqrt{a_n} < \varepsilon$. What can we conclude now?

> As @DonAntonio has mentioned, I assumed $a_n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The A by @VIVID is fine. I want to mention that it is useful to know more than one equivalent definition of convergence and of non-convergence, e.g.

(i). $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=A$ iff for every $r>0$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N:|a_n-A|\ge r\}$ is finite.

(ii). $[\neg (\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=B)\,]$ iff there exists $s>0$ such that the set $\{n\in \Bbb N:|b_n-B|\ge s\}$ is infinite.

Suppose $a_n=(b_n)^2$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ . We can use (ii) with $B=0$ to prove that $$[\,\neg ( \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0)\,]\implies \neg (\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0).$$

If $s>0$ and  the set $\{n\in \Bbb N:|b_n|\ge s\}$ is infinite then, with $r=s^2>0,$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N:|a_n|\ge r\}$ is infinite, which by another instance of (ii) implies  $\neg (\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0).$